# How to simulate an X11 key event with a given layout index?

Tags: keyboard, x11

By looking at the events it's clear what keyboard layout index is used:

```
$ xev -id 0x5c00010
...
KeyPress event, serial 43, synthetic NO, window 0x5c00010,
    root 0x1e5, subw 0x0, time 30630922, (173,469), root:(1053,887),
    state 0x4000, keycode 40 (keysym 0x64, d), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (64) "d"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (64) "d"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
...
```

The "state 0x4000" means the third one. Four seems to be the limit: 0x0---, 0x2---, 0x4---, 0x6---.

Where is this mask documented? Is there a constant or a function to fill the state value? I'd like to be able to generate the key events with a layout of my choosing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/libX11/specs/XKB/xkblib.html:

> Normally, the Xkb-aware server reports keyboard state in the state member of events such as a KeyPress event and ButtonPress event, encoded as follows:
>
> ```
>     bits  meaning  
>     15      0   
>     13-14   Group index  
>     8-12    Pointer Buttons  
>     0-7     Modifiers
> ```

"Group" is Xkb-speak for layout.